# Object Oriented Programming - temporarily grouping objects and releasing them

Tags: object, instance, grouping, move, concept

I'm really just looking for some direction here, I've been teaching myself and at this point I don't really know what concept to look up. Perhaps I have a fundamental error in my understanding of how to do object oriented programming, if so, please point that out. :)

I've got a few project ideas and all of them involve this same concept; That is, grouping a bunch of objects, doing something to them, and then releasing them. Perhaps I'm not thinking about this in the best way, but let me give you some conceptual examples to show you what I'm trying to do.

Say there are different players in a game, each an object. There are also spaceships in the game, also objects (imagine the millennium falcon). I can move the players and the spaceships individually  (player.move or spaceship.move). But what I want to do is move the ship and the player when the player boards the spaceship. My conceptual framework for doing so is to create a new object, that when moved, moves both the ship and all players associated with the ship(i.e. inside the ship, walking around). The player needs to retain the ability to move independently of this grouping of object though (think about walking around inside the ship, while also being moved with the ship). The players can board and leave ships freely, so there needs to be a function/method to add them to the ship, rather than it being, say, a scripted/hard programmed event (please excuse my misuse of terminology :P)

Another example would be the found in molecules for a chemistry program. Each atom in a carbon chain would be its own object (tracking things like number of bonds, proton#, charge, etc). But the molecule itself would be a larger object, that is filled in with carbon objects. The molecule object would need to change dynamically, as in when reactions were done to it; new atoms would become a part of its structure some would leave its structure. Pretty much, I need to be able to load/unload atoms to the molecule depending on which reaction, and where the reaction takes place.

Another example is found in a Rubik's cube game where all 6 sides are visible to the player. When one row is shifted, an entire side rotates 90 degrees. The way I had imagine programming this is to have each individual square as an object; when I need to rotate a side, I will group the 6 objects of that side, and rotate and spin them about a common point and then release the objects from the group so the cube could then be further manipulated and solved.

I can probably hard-program these things, but I can't imagine how to do it, well, dynamically. I'd like to have these set up so that I have a method that adds or removes from my grouping of objects. Is this type of programming possible? Is there a better approach to achieving what I'm trying to do?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would deal with this would be for the container object to have some way of knowing what is associated with it at any given time so that it can effect changes. Let's use your spaceship example. You would define your spaceship class such that each spaceship contains an array of players on board. Every time a player boards the spaceship, you would call spaceship.board(player), indicating that a given player is now on board the spaceship. Then you would define spaceship.move to also call player.move on each player currently on board i.e. any element of the player array. Assuming every spaceship and every player knew its coordinates, the spaceship.move function would update the spaceship's coordinates directly and then depend upon player.move to perform the internal update for each player. This way, any time the spaceship moved you would also affect any player on board. Then, you could define a spaceship.disembark function to have players leave the spaceship.

An example of this could be:

1. Create spaceship with initial location
2. Create player with initial location
3. Add player to spaceship, update player location to be equal to to spaceship location
4. Move player up 5 units (for example) by calling player.move function
5. Move spaceship up 100 units by calling spaceship.move. This will also move the player by calling player.move, so the player is still 5 units up relative to the spaceships position
6. Have player leave spaceship
7. Move spaceship down 100 units. Since the player is no longer on the ship, the player's position will not be updated by spaceship.move and will remain the same

Answer (score 0):

What you speak of is one object containing a set of another object, and those objects can be added and removed constantly. I'll take your concept of a spaceship and give an example how it can be implemented:

```
class Ship {
  list<Person> crew;

  void board(Person player) {
    crew.add(player);
  }

  void unboard(Person player) {
    crew.remove(player);
  }

  void Move() {
    //do move things
    foreach(Person player in crew) {
      player.Move();
    }
  }
```

What you have to be careful of is to have the responsibilities in the correct class. For example if a Player is boarded, does he still needs to perform a move, or can if you would ask it its location, that question be redirected to the ship it has boarded?

```
Class Person {
  Ship? Boarded;

  void Board(Ship ship) {
    Boarded = ship;
    Boarded.board(self);
  }

  void unboard() {
    if (Boarded != null) {
      this.location = Boarded.location;
      Boarded.unboard(self);
      Boarded = null;
    }
  }

  Location location() {
    if (Boarded != null) {
      return Boarded.location;
    } else {
      return location;
    }
  }
}
```

As an alternative in the concept of "A class should only be responsible for one thing" you could introduce a class responsible for moving objects:

```
Class Mover {
  list<Object> objects

  void Move(Location location) {
    foreach(Object object in objects) {
      object.location = location;
    }
  }
}
```